# Using Asynchronous Methods for lots of repetitive api calls to Ebay

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, ebay-api

I am using the .Net api framework to make calls to Ebay to update the shipping status.  I have some code that works but the Ebay api is notoriously slow and can take from 3 - 5 seconds per call.  On about 50 items its a little slow.

Here is my working code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Query query = new Query(OrderItem.Schema);
        query.Top = "50";
        query.WHERE(OrderItem.Columns.SourceId, 1);
        query.ORDER_BY(OrderItem.Columns.OrderItemId, "DESC");
        List<int> salesIds = new List<int>();

        OrderItemCollection col = OrderItemController.FetchByQuery(query);

        foreach(OrderItem oi in col)
        {
            GetOrdersCall getOrders = new GetOrdersCall(EbayContextHelper.GetContext(YellowLily.Business.Enums.ApplicationSource.YellowLily));
            getOrders.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);
            getOrders.OrderRole = TradingRoleCodeType.Seller;
            getOrders.OrderIDList = new StringCollection(new[] { oi.ExtOrderId });
            // this fires of an HTTP request behind the scenes 
            getOrders.Execute();

            foreach (OrderType order in getOrders.OrderList)
            {
                salesIds.Add(order.ShippingDetails.SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber);
            }
        }

    }
```

Please note with the code that I have substituted updating the shipping status to just pulling data i.e fetching an order and returning some data as I don't want to mess with my real orders while testing this.

I am a reasonable coder but the asynchronous library is very confusing for me.    Could anyone point me in the right direction on how I can convert this to an async call?

I have a couple of concerns:

- If I am quickly firing of 50 asynchronous calls is this detrimental or does the framework handle this for me?

  - I obviously need to see the result come back to ensure I know it has succeeded.

  Thanks

Comment: Ebay doesn't have any `async` calls, they are all standard vanilla synchronous ones. Secondly you can call them in an asynchronous manner though. Note i think they do employ some sort of anti throttling mechanism, as calling 50 calls parallel wont get you 50 Times the performance. Also because they aren't `async`, you just wont be able to use up 50 thread pool threads efficiently without some work arounds

Comment: I dont think you are really at the stage of asking a question about this. Firstly i think you should start understanding threads and tasks and TPL, secondly start experimenting with the TPL library and parallel calls, thirdly i would then start experimenting with this knowledge and the Ebay Api.

Comment: Thaks for your comments...I will

Comment: It's very hard to help you with the code as it is. You need to provide a [mcve] for us to work with. That would mean enough information for us to set up your code and run it (preferably in a Console App).